# android browser does not launch app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am unable to get the app I have written to launch when a certain url is passed back to the browser.

When the user launches the default browser and goes to the where my server is running for example: www.test.com, a list of films and books are displayed on the remote server. When the user selects one of these items i.e. a film or book - the server sends back a url that starts with bb:// and contains the uri link.fil?data=1. So the url looks like this when sent back from the server:

```
    bb://link.fil?data=1
```

Currently I have the manifest which declares the following filter intent:

```
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data
                android:scheme="bb"
                android:host="test.com"
                android:path="/.*"
                android:pathPattern="/.*\\.*"/>
                />
            <data
                android:scheme="bb"
                android:host="www.test.com"
                android:path="/.*"
                android:pathPattern="/.*\\.*"
                />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

What I am trying to make happen is when the user selects a book of film the returning url launches my app.

After following many of the examples on line I still don't seem to be able to get this to work, and would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lay with chrome and mozilla they were rejecting the invocation - when using the default browser on android the app was called from the browser as was required. So I am marking the previous answer as correct but the problem lies with iframe which chrome and mozzila are now using- Maybe some one has the answer for fixing these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="link.fil"
                android:scheme="bb" />
</intent-filter>
```